# J2SE Question, constructor auto run?

Tags: java

I have wrote C# few years and start to learn java,
today i saw a sample is strange ,which is cannot happen in C#.

from
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Drawrectangles.htm

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame {

  public static void main(String[] a){
    MainClass f = new MainClass();
    f.setSize(300,300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }


  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 60, 50);
    g.fillRect(100, 10, 60, 50);
    g.drawRoundRect(190, 10, 60, 50, 15, 15);
    g.fillRoundRect(70, 90, 140, 100, 30, 40);
  }
}
```

the constructor paint() will be fire on main(), and the parameter - "g" haven't initialize anythings, is it a hidden feature on java but which is not legal on OOP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What should be illegal here? You are extending a `JFrame` and only overriding the method `paint()` (method, not constructor). There rest is all inherited behaviour.

If you check the source code of `JFrame` and its ancestors you will see that at some point the call to `setVisibile()` will call `paint()`. And also provides a correct `Graphics` object.

---

The behavior is the same as in this mini example. Which will output "`Bar`" on the command line. Which makes sense. You override the `runMe()` method which is called in the constructor of `Foo` which you inherit in `Bar` as you don't override it with/provide your own.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Bar();
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public Foo() { runMe(); }
    public void runMe() { System.out.println("Foo"); }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    public void runMe() { System.out.println("Bar");}
}
```

Comment: thanks you for answer, i never thought it is override , because in C# world it need to state by "overrides" keyword.
After i search in java doc,
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html
i know java can skip the keyword .thanks you for help

Comment: Yep but should better add it (`@Override`) so the compiler warns you when you think you overwrite something but actually aren't

Answer (score 3):

paint() is not a constructor. paint() is a method which will be called by Swing when it needs to draw the frame you have created.

Try reading a [tutorial on Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/) and the Javadocs for [JFrame](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at this line

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame
```

You're getting lot's of extra function from the JFrame class, including the setting up of the Graphic context.

Note that **paint()** is not a constructor, it's a method of the class, it's called as a result of the setting of the frame to to be visible.